# Could not determine java version from '11.0.1'

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I'm working on Windows 10 and just starting with react-native. from https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

One of the first steps to get started is to run: react-native run-android. But I'm getting this error:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue around November 2018, and it seems like React Native depends on Java 8 instead of Java 11 for Android. You can find it [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html.%20Just%20read%20more%20on%20this%20page%20https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started) - under "Building Projects with Native Code", choose "Windows for Development OS" and "Android for Target OS"

Comment: but they said "React Native also requires a recent version of the Java SE Development Kit (JDK)"

Comment: Yeah I saw that but after that it says **If you already have a JDK on your system, make sure it is version 8 or newer** so I tried version 8 and it worked. I guess its because Java started getting huge changes from Java 9 so Java 8 seems like a stable version for React Native. Doesn't work for you?

Comment: @KouroshNeyestani check this out https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11755